# What is the meaning of this notation? (Probability)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-integrals

[image]

What does the subscript " 1 | 1 " mean in this context?

Comment: Looks like the probability of one observation ($Y_{t_3}=y_3$) conditioned on one other observation ($Y_{t_1}=y_1$). Whereas $P_2$ for example is the unconditional probability of getting two particular observations.

Comment: I don't really understand the implication of conditioning an observation on itself, unless the redundancy is itself important

Comment: It's generally not the same observation, though of course if you condition an observation on itself then the probability will be $1$. The numbers are just referring to how many observations are in the "event" and how many are in the "condition". In particular you could write $P_n=P_{n \mid 0}$. The observations themselves are in the arguments (again as I said here you are looking at $P(Y_{t_3}=y_3 \mid Y_{t_1}=y_1)$).